# Chain Rule Differentiation Functional Decomposition via Addition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, chain-rule

This might be obvious, but I am not able to understand it. Would appreciate any help.

Let there be a function which can be decomposed into $\ k$ functions using addition $\ f = \sum_{i=1}^k f_i$. We want to find partial derivative of $\ f$ w.r.t. $\ y$. Is there something wrong in the following approach? If yes, then what is the problem. Is there a simple proof of the chain rule that contradicts this, or proves it? Thanks!

$$
\frac{\partial(f)}{\partial(y)} = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial(f_i)}{\partial(y)} = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\partial(f_i)}{\partial(x_i)}\cdot\frac{\partial(x_i)}{\partial(y)}$$

Comment: What are these functions $x_i$ exactly? Are there defined such that $f_i\equiv f_i(x_i(y))$? Or are they just general (euclidean) coordinates?

Comment: Yes. The way you put. The variables are combinations of $x_i$ and $y$.

Comment: So the variables $x_i$ are also dependent on $y$?

Comment: Yes. Is there any general guideline to when chain rules over summations can be broken the way I wrote above?

Comment: The way you did it is exactly the definition of the chain rule for multivariate functions: https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/multichainrule/ So it it correct